# ansible regex_replace in command

Tags: regex, linux, ansible

I'am using ansible to deploy filestore on GCP, I need to get IP from instance and use it to create mount point.
gcloud working fine but it's return bracket and simple quote with ip.
Someone can help me to remove these caractere please ? My regex command doesn't work and i'am newbie with regex.

Error tasks mount cannot resolv come from '' in ip.stdout

ansible code:

```
- name: get info
  shell: gcloud filestore instances describe "{{nfs_id}}" --project=xxxx-xxxx --zone=xxxxx-b --format='get(networks.ipAddresses)'
  register: ip


 - name: master_setup.yml --> DEBUG REGEX
   debug:
     var: "{{ 'ip.stdout' | regex_replace('([^\\.]*)\\.(.+)$', '\\1') }}"
    
- name: print mount point test
  debug:
    msg: "{{ip.stdout}}:/{{nfs_name }}"

- name:  Mount an NFS volume
  mount:
    fstype: nfs
    state: mounted
    opts: rw,sync,hard,intr
    src: "{{ip.stdout}:/{{nfs_name }}"
    path: /mnt/nexus-storage
```

result of ansible playbook execution

```
TASK [install_nexus : master_setup.yml --> DEBUG REGEX] ********************************************************
ok: [nexus-xxxx.xxx.xxxxx] => {
    "ip": {
        "ansible_facts": {
            "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
        },
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "ggcloud filestore instances describe "{{nfs_id}}" --project=xxxx-xxxx --zone=xxxxx-b --format='get(networks.ipAddresses)'",
        "delta": "0:00:01.013823",
        "end": "2021-03-14 21:23:32.398266",
        "failed": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2021-03-14 21:23:31.384443",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "['1xx.xxx.xx.2']",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "['1xx.xxx.xx.2']"
        ]
    }
}

TASK [install_nexus : print mount point test] ******************************************************************
ok: [nexus-xxxx.xxx.xxxxx] => {
    "msg": "['1xx.xxx.xx.2']:/nfsnexusnew"
}

TASK [install_nexus : Mount an NFS volume] *********************************************************************
[WARNING]: sftp transfer mechanism failed on [nexus-ppd.preprod.d-aim.com]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed
information
fatal: [nexus-xxxx.xxx.xxxxx]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error mounting /mnt/nexus-storage: mount.nfs: Failed to resolve server '1xx.xxx.xx.2': Name or service not known\n"}
```

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Resolved doing this, it's not very sexy but it's working. If someone find a solution please forward me it.
I have used 2 regex because I don't how to remove simple quote and bracket in one line:

```
- name: get info
  shell: gcloud filestore instances describe "{{nfs_id}}" --project=xxxx-xxxx --zone=xxxxx-b --format='get(networks.ipAddresses)' > /tmp/nfs-ip.txt

- name: sed regex to delete []
  shell: sed -i 's/[][]//g' /tmp/nfs-ip.txt

- name: sed regex to delete ''
  shell: sed -i 's|["'\'']||g'  /tmp/nfs-ip.txt

- name: register result in var ip
  shell: cat /tmp/nfs-ip.txt
  register: ip


- name:  Mount an NFS volume
  mount:
    fstype: nfs
    state: mounted
    opts: rw,sync,hard,intr
    src: "{{ip.stdout}}:/{{nfs_name }}"
    path: /mnt/nexus-storage
```

Answer (score 0):

Q: *"**Cannot resolve ip.stdout**"*

A: The value stored in *ip.stdout* is a string

```yaml
   "ip": {
          ...
        "stdout": "['1xx.xxx.xx.2']",
          ...
   }
```

Use the filters *from_yaml* and *first* to get the first item of the list, e.g.

```yaml
    src: "{{ ip.stdout|from_yaml|first }}:/{{ nfs_name }}"
```

Comment: Hello Dear, Thx i'll try this.